# href doesn't appear as a clickable link

Tags: html

I am trying to make an unordered list with clickable links, but none of them appears like that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

     <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest1</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest2</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest3</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest4</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest5</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting a list of clickable links, but I get a list containing the set items but without their clickable links.

I am new to web developing so I am assuming I have overlooked something.

edit: I am using a plugin named Emmet whivh I used to make the  block/section.

Comment: It’s `<a href="#">sampletest1</a>`. The links have no content otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing the anchor tag before the content.

```
            <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest1</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest2</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>sampletest3</li>
```

It gives nothing because there is no label for the anchor tag.

You should change like

```
            <li><a href="#">sampletest1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sampletest2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sampletest3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write words into link content
like:

```
<a href="#">sampletest1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you must write your text inside the `a`-tag,
like this:

```
<li><a href="#">sampletest1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sampletest2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sampletest3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sampletest4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sampletest5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

     <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sampletest1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sampletest2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sampletest3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sampletest4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sampletest5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```